# Can I put dnsmasq in front of a win2k3 DC and have clients use dnsmasq as primary DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dnsmasq

I am running a mixed LAN, and have XP client PCs on a 2k3 domain (and therefore use 2k3 as primary DNS).  For political reasons I need to run dnsmasq server in front of it and point other DNS namespaces to other DNS servers.  Is it possible for XP clients to use dnsmasq as primary DNS, and have dnsmasq forward appropriate queries to 2k3 without breaking AD?

Setting dnsmasq as secondary DNS is not an option.

Comment: so if I understand your question correctly, you want dnsmasq to be the DNS server for an AD domain. Am I right on that?

Comment: this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell Dnsmasq will not forward dynamic DNS update requests.  if you can get away without DNS updates then you may be able to use Dnsnasq.  Yo may be able to get away with this if you have another name resolutions system like WINS setup.

Unless you plan on manually set a lot of important records,you DCs will need to point at the AD integrated zones.

Comment: is it important for the DC to have clients populate its zone with DDNS?

Comment: ugh..... WINS. It's 2010, aren't we over that yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use dnsmasq for that.
You can find a tutorial on [linvirt](http://www.linvirt.nl/netwerk/windows/dnsmasq-ad.php),
the tutorial is in dutch, but you only need the code ;)